# Leetcode220 error: incomparable types: int and <null>

Tags: java, algorithm, treeset

I received an error when compiled the code below, which is "incomparable types: int and " on line 10.

```
public class Solution {
public boolean containsNearbyAlmostDuplicate(int[] nums, int k, int t) {
    if (nums == null || k <= 0 || t < 0 || nums.length < 2) return false;

    TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int floor = set.floor(nums[i] + t);//return largest number smaller than nums[i] + t or null
        int ceil = set.ceiling(nums[i] - t);//return least number larger than num[i] - t or null

        if ((floor != null && floor >= nums[i]) || (ceil != null && ceil <= nums[i])) {
            return true;
        }

        set.add(nums[i]);

        if (set.size() > k) {
            set.remove(nums[i - k]);
        }
    }

    return false;
}}
```

but if I add final keyword before treeset, floor and ceil, the code will be compiled successfully. Could anyone help me explain what's going on? Thanks.

```
...
final TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    final Integer floor = set.floor(nums[i] + t);//return largest number smaller than nums[i] + t or null
    final Integer ceil = set.ceiling(nums[i] - t);//return least number larger than num[i] - t or null
...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`int floor` defines `floor` as a basic `int` type. `Integer floor` defines `floor` as a non-trivial, `class` type. `null` is used only with non-trivial types

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with the `final` keyword (It will work without it anyway). You just can't compare a primitive value (`int`) to `null`. Instead, you should use a corresponding object (`Integer`).